# Why Time complexity of Fibonacci using for loop is O(n^2) and not O(n)?

Tags: algorithm, time-complexity, fibonacci

Why is the time complexity is calculated as O(n^2) instead of O(n) for below algo.

```
FibList(n)
    array[0-n] Create Array            O(n)
    F[0] <- 0                          O(1)
    F[1] <- 1                          O(1)

    for i from 2 to n                  O(n)
        F[i] <- F[i-1] + F[i-2]        O(n) 

    return F[n]                        O(1)
```

O(n) + O(1) + O(1) + O(n) O(n) + O(1) = O(n^2)

Comment: `F[i] <- F[i-1] + F[i-2]` is `O(1)`

Comment: Creating an array of size n is also O(1) nowadays.

Comment: @Adam that's an assumption. With a different assumption, namely that that F[i-1] + F[i-2] costs O(log_2(max(F[i-1], F[i-2]))) (that is, the cost depends on the number of bits), you get O(n^2). See my answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you assume the cost of adding an integer with `k1` bits to one with `k2` bits is proportional to max(`k1`, `k2`) (which is the so-called "bit" cost model, or "logarithmic" cost model), then the time complexity of the code you've produced is O(n^2).

That's because F(i) is (almost) proportional to phi^i, where phi is the Golden ratio. That means F(i) has ~i bits.

So the cost of:

```
for i from 2 to n
    F[i] <- F[i-1] + F[i-2]
```

is proportional to (1 + 2 + 3 + ... n-1) which is n(n-1)/2, and thus O(n^2).

If you assume that addition of arbitrary-sized integers is O(1), then the code is O(n).

For background on cost models, see this section on wikipedia https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Analysis_of_algorithms#Cost_models which says

> One must be careful here; for instance, some analyses count an
>   addition of two numbers as one step. This assumption may not be
>   warranted in certain contexts. For example, if the numbers involved in
>   a computation may be arbitrarily large, the time required by a single
>   addition can no longer be assumed to be constant.

Incidentally, the method used in your question, of writing the maximum complexity of each line and then multiplying nested ones, is not a valid way of computing tight-bound complexities, although it works in cases where all the complexities are polynomials, which in this case they are.

Comment: Loop iterations and number of bits are not related to one another. So you will never get `n^2`. Maybe m*n. Finding max is O(1) anyway as int number of bits is most probably 4 bytes.

Comment: @TonyTannous F[i] has ~i bits, and i is the loop counter, so they are related in this case.

Comment: Maybe i bits out of sizeof(int) bits in use. I don't know any operation which will cost i bits and not sizeof(int).

Comment: @TonyTannous How about the addition of two bignums?

Comment: Correct me if I am wrong, adding any two numbers would cost sizeof(type).

Comment: A bignum (which is necessary to compute arbitrary sized results), uses a heap-allocated array to store the digits (perhaps in base 256 or some other large base). The cost of adding two of these depends on the sizes of their arrays. `sizeof(bignum)` won't capture this heap-allocated array.